# How to remove Title from highchart flags

Tags: highcharts

I need to remove the Flag title from a chart created with Highchart. Any ideas how this can be done?

Is no title is set or set to null it shows A by default.

```
type : 'flags',
name: 'Notable Event',
legend: 'Notable Event',
title: {
    text: null, // OR if no title is set it displays A
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set transparent color, by rgba.

```
{   
                type : 'flags',
                data : [{
                    x : Date.UTC(2015, 5, 8),
                    title : '',
                    style:{
                        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                    }
                }]
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/95ce3n2q/

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. In my case I am using flag image as          `shape: 'url(red_icon.png)'`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the title with this plotOptions:

```
plotOptions: {
  flags: {
    title: ''
  }
}
```

Check this documentation for more info:

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.flags.title